# UITapGestureRecognizer fails on iPad in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, landscape, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am working on a single-view app that has a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. I noticed that when I tried it on my iPad, the taps weren't being recognized. After I zoomed the app with the 1x/2x button, the taps started working. What am I doing wrong?

I have narrowed this down to a very small sample. I started with the XCode "Single View Application", and the following is the `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    info = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 20)];
    [self.view addSubview:info];

    tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapper];
}
```

Here is what I know so far:

- Works on iPhone-sized screens.
- Works on iPad in *portrait* orientation.
- Fails on iPad in *landscape* orientation, until the view is zoomed with 1x/2x, then it starts working (and continues working after zooming back to the original zoom level).
- Exhibits the same behaviour with the iPad simulator.

The complete code is in a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ghewgill/TapTest) so you can view the whole thing or try it. XCode 4.5.1, iPad retina, iOS 6.0.1.

Comment: For me, the project works fine in iPad simulator from the beginning without zoom.

Comment: @ParamasivanSamuttiram: Interesting, thanks. I wonder what could be different.

Comment: @GregHewgill I see the same behavior you do when I start it in landscape mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that if I remove all of the entries under "Supported interface orientation" in the app's plist, this problem goes away. Or if you check the "Hide during application launch" option for the "Status Bar" settings on the Summary screen of the Target settings, this also fixes it:

[image: hide during application launch]

There's no logical reason that I can see that either of these options *should* fix this bug, but they both do.

Obviously, if you do play around with the "Supported interface orientation" option, in iOS 6, you can still programmatically control the permitted orientations via [`supportedInterfaceOrientations`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations) ([`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:) in iOS 5).

Comment: This seems like an iOS 6 bug and I have reported it via http://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: If I remove all the supported interface orientations, the app appears to always start in portrait mode, even on the iPad when held in landscape mode. That is, the status bar shifts to the side (short side) of the screen, then back to the top (long side). Of course the supported interface orientation setting controls what happens while the app is launching, before any of its code can run. (My app is designed for landscape mode only.)

Comment: Thanks for submitting the bug report for the problem (which I agree seems like a bug), but unfortunately this workaround doesn't seem like it's going to work for me.

Comment: That was it! If I start with the original project (as on GitHub) and simply tick "Hide during application launch" for the status bar, the original problem mysteriously seems to go away. I still want the status bar to appear while the app is running, so I set the app `statusBarHidden = NO` in `viewDidLoad`. That causes the status bar to disappear for a short time while the app is loading and then reappear, which is acceptable for now.